# How to remove space of text transform?

Tags: css, css-transitions, transform, css-transforms

I have a small issue I want to fix, but can't find any good answer : I search for it  and found some use full answers but they did not solve my problem .I use

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg)
```

to rotate text due to which space added.Now i have to remove extra space .
Here is a jsfiddle to show the problem:    [https://jsfiddle.net/raxa/8yLwheo0/](https://jsfiddle.net/raxa/88fdymL5/)

Here is project  [link](http://arslankhalid.com/tt/)
I want to remove space and want to keep them close to each other and want a space of 5px between them .
Sorry for my English 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have a absolute position div, there is no spaces... just places in the wrong place

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to the extra padding you have on the `.verticle_td` elements...just adjust it like so:

```
table .Title td.verticle_td {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```css
table .Title {
  background: #105B9D;
}
table .Title td {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}
table .Title td.verticle_td {
  padding-left: 0;
}
table .Title .rank {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  top: 54px;
}
table .Title .verticle-text {
  white-space: pre;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1.5em;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
table .Title .verticle_td {
  top: 35px;
}
.first_tr {
  Background: #06355D;
  border-top: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class='Title'>
    <td class='rank'>RANK</td>
    <td>COMPANY NAME</td>

    <td class="verticle_td">
      <div class='verticle-text'>On Page Optimization</div>
    </td>
    <td class="verticle_td">
      <div class='verticle-text'>Off Page Optimization</div>
    </td>
    <td class="verticle_td">
      <div class='verticle-text'>Needs Analysis</div>
    </td>
    <td class="verticle_td">
      <div class='verticle-text'>Keyword Analysis</div>
    </td>
    <td class="verticle_td">
      <div class='verticle-text'>Reporting Methods</div>
    </td>
    <td class="verticle_td">
      <div class='verticle-text'>Overall Score</div>
    </td>
    <td class="verticle_td">
      <div class='verticle-text'>Change in Rank</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have updated my question and also provided the project link please take a review.I try through above changes but it does not work for me

Comment: Your project link does not have the same structure of the fiddle. The fiddle has divs...your linked project does not.

Comment: Well now you have invalidated everything. I don't think you can rotate text **without** wrapping elements like divs.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you mean correctly, you need to change your `transform-origin` so that the new origin is positioned at 50% of the height of the element:

```
table .Title .verticle-text {
    white-space: pre;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1.5em;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8yLwheo0/1/)

You are currently rotating your element around the top leftcorner. The above will rotate around a point positioned at the left-hand vertical centre.